# How to draw an image inside Rounded Rectangle or inside a shape like circle?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT and I want to draw some image inside a shape and image should be croped by a shape.
I use the following code to draw a rectangle for example. How to draw image only inside shape?

```
   QPen pen(Qt::black,penWidth);
   pen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);

   QPicture picture;
   picture.load("drawing.pic"); 


   painter->setPen(pen);
   painter->drawPicture(0,0, picture);

   painter->drawRoundedRect( (QRectF(x, y, height, width),radius,radius);
```

PS. Can I load an image to brush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a QBrush for painter.

```
 QBrush brush(QPixmap("file.png"));
 painter->setBrush(brush);
```

It will draw the rounded rect filled with file.png image.

Comment: if you need to play with the alpha of the image then painter->setOpacity(0.2);